# How to add Ckeditor data in to sql server using linq approach

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, insert, database-connection

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am stuch here how i insert the data in to database using Ckeditor webform asp.net using linq approach . Remaining all are working fine . Please help me to resolve this 
Thanks

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show your code instead of post it in image

Comment: There is no difference between a value from TextBox, TextArea and a and a TextArea that is used by CKEditor. They are all strings. Set `TextMode="MultiLine"` to create a textarea in html.

Comment: it gives error .

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (editor1="<p>hjbjb</p>
").
Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. I

Comment: try this <textarea cols="20" rows="2" id="editor1" class="editor1" runat="server"></textarea>. and in the code behind use editor1.Value please keep in mind that when rendering the control asp.net will assign it a different id than editor1 on the client side.